# how to rip your own acapella

Tags: production, sampling

I've been looking through many tutorials online and none of them really seem to work for me. Ive tried using Audacity but it was a major failure.  I've tried the inversion technique. There is a remix I'd like to make to the track Get Up by Technotronic, however I cannot find an acapella anywhere.  What is the best way for me to get this acapella myself.   There must be a way to do it because there are so many acapellas created daily by people who aren't in connection with the artist for the raw audio file.  It in no way needs to be perfect.

If there is no answer, then at least I think the community would benefit from knowing the process.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finding an instrumental and using the phase inversion trick is almost always the most reliable way to get usable vocals. Unfortunately if it's a pro-mastered instrumental, the waveforms won't be an exact match so there will be odd phasing quirks and bleed on the resulting a cappella.

You could also hunt for Guitar Hero / Rock Band "mogg" files (multichannel OGG) and open in Audacity to extract their vocal tracks...

Comment: Hey thanks,  is there any tutorials or information that you could provide to get this done?

Answer (score 0):

Might want to try using [ISSE](http://isse.sourceforge.net/), a really good free open-source sound separation tool. Or, if you want to pay some money, Izotope Rx might be your friend as well.